# How to add a SOAP header via JAX-WS?

Tags: soap, jax-ws, soapheader

Our system requires adding some header information in the SOAP message. So how does this be implemented by JAX-WS. I know one way to achieve this is adding 
`@WebParam(name = "login", header = true),` but this solution is not what we want. We want one solution which doesn't need to change the endpoint interface.

Comment: Do you need to consume a webservice as a client or implement a web service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to write an interceptor which will implement SOAPHandler to intercept the request.